# I am looking for a way to do a multi-column Dropdown Listbox using Kendo in an Angular 7 project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, kendo-ui

I'm attempting to recreate the multi-column Kendo DropDownList found at the following link.

[kendoDropDownList](https://dojo.telerik.com/OWEgOn/3)

I've been able to recreate most of it using the following code, but it will not display the data properly.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-tablebox',
    //  templateUrl: './tablebox.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./tablebox.component.scss'],
      template: `
      <div>
      <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:400px;"
        [defaultItem]="defaultItem"
        [data]= "data"
        [textField]= "'band'"
        [valueField]= "'id'"

      > 
    <ng-template kendoDropDownListHeaderTemplate>
                        <table>
                          <tr class="combo-tr">
                            <td class="combo-hd-td">Band</td>
                            <td class="combo-hd-td">Song</td>
                            <td class="combo-hd-td">Album</td>
                          </tr>
                      </table>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template kendoDropDownListValueTemplate let-dataItem>
                      <span>
                        <table>
                          <tr class="combo-tr">
                            <td class="combo-td">{{dataItem.band}}</td>
                            <td class="combo-td">{{dataItem.song}}</td>
                            <td class="combo-td">{{dataItem.album}}</td>
                          </tr>
                      </table>
                    </span>                  
    </ng-template>

      </kendo-dropdownlist>

    </div> `
    })

    export class TableboxComponent {

      public defaultItem: { text: string, value: number } = { text: "Select item...", value: null };

      public data = [
        { id: 1, band: "Iron Maiden", song: "Wasted Years", album: "Ed Hunter" },
        { id: 2, band: "Metallica", song: "Enter Eandman", album: "Metallica" },
        { id: 3, band: "Mr. Big", song: "Seven Impossible Days", album: "Japandemonium" },
        { id: 4, band: "Unknown Band", song: "Some Song", album: "The Album" }
      ];



      constructor() { }

    }
```

The component displays as follows:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCyVI.png)

Thanks in advance.

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `kendoDropDownListItemTemplate` instead of `kendoDropDownListValueTemplate`.

`kendoDropDownListValueTemplate` is the template used for the item that appears in the dropdown after you've selected an item.

`kendoDropDownListItemTemplate` is the template used for the items in the list.